# Move files to folder name contained in the file name

Tags: batch-file, dos

I am trying to move files that has partial data in its name to new folder of that string in the filename!

```
myfiles[sql-data-2232]sql.dat  [want to move it and create folder sql-data-2232]
myfiles[jpg-data-2232]jpg.img  [want to move it and create folder jpg-data-2232]
myfiles[whatever-number]xyz.xyz [want to move it and create folder whatever-number]
```

brackets in the file name contains the folder name which the file to be moved to!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test this on a folder of sample files.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "myfiles*" /b /a-d ') do (
   for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%b in ("%%a") do MD "%%b" 2>nul & move "%%a" "%%b" >nul
)
echo done
pause
```

Comment: file names with spaces in it does not behave the same, for example my files[blah blah] or myfile(space)[blah blah] it would be in a folder name as of the file name till the first space, folder "my" and folder "myfiles"!

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  Can you give me a real example that is failing and what the folder name is?

Comment: I used your code as follows
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "*.dat" /b /a-d ') do ...

as some of the filenames are different than "myfiles",
dc branch[sql-data9999]sql.dat
dc-casa[sql-data-9999sql.dat
Now with the above files, the folder name was "dc"

Comment: Is that one filename or two?  I tried it as two filenames and it works, except the second filename is missing a `]` so the second foldername is longer.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with tags here!
[pre]
dc branch[sql-data9999]sql.dat 
dc-casa[sql-data-9999]sql.dat
{/pre]
the above will be moved to _dc_ folder, while to should be the folder name as in the brackets!

Comment: That [pre] isn't part of the filename, right? They won't be moved to a `dc` folder.  Try the code as posted in an empty folder with those two files that you have shown.

Comment: [pre] is not part of the filename, the idea is the some file names has 'space' or even '-' in the first portion of the file name before '['.